# Use sequence for auto increment PK of existing table

Tags: oracle

I've an existing table **emp_table(pk_emp, name, address, contact, dob)**. This table has more than 10000 records. Now I need a sequence to insert data in this table with **next pk_emp** value. How  should I create this sequence which will start from the next value of **pk_emp** and can be used for future insertions in this table.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm `create or replace sequence ... start with ...`

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can create sequence which starts from *any value* you want (all you have to do is to put `START WITH`):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm

something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE pk_emp_seq
     START WITH 10000 -- specify the right value here
   INCREMENT BY 1
        NOCACHE
        NOCYCLE;
```

**Edit**: in case you want a *dynamic* implementation, try putting the code above into `execute immediate`:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.htm#LNPLS01317

```
declare 
  start_with emp_table.pk_emp%Type; 
begin
  select max(pk_emp) + 1
    into start_with
    from emp_table; 

  -- the same create sequence as in the sample above, but with dynamic "parameter"
  execute immediate 
    'CREATE SEQUENCE pk_emp_seq 
          START WITH ' || To_Char(start_with) || 
    '   INCREMENT BY 1
             NOCACHE
             NOCYCLE';  
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I also did the same it works fine. But I need a dynamic value at start with clause that should be the next maximum value of pk_emp. This is because the query need to run on different environment where I don't know the max value of pk_emp.

Comment: @Vimal: if you want a *script* which you can run on *different databases* (schemas) you can try `execute immediate`